# Jupyter notebook imports old version, despite updating sklearn

Tags: windows, scikit-learn, jupyter

According to other posts, the problem is that I updated `sklearn` in the system terminal and not the terminal offered by the Jupyter interface.

It turns out that Windows does not support the terminal within Jupyter. So, how can I get `sklearn 0.18` imported to a notebook?

Thanks!